# How to configure the VPN connection in Linux Mint

Tags: linux, vpn

I need to connect to VPN server from linux mint but can't.

I've successfully connected to VPN server from windows with follow credentials:

"login" : "login"
"password" : "password"
"key" : "keykeykey"
"connection name" : "name"
"server name" : "vpn.servername.at"

As I understand - for connection is important to use all of these data (I mean that connection configuration must have both password and key)

So, I opened my connections settings and see two varisnt of VPN connection:

- OpenVPN
- PPTP

1. Attempt with OpenVPN:

[image]

As you can see - there in't exist the field where I can put the KEY, that was necessary in the windows. I do not sure that the Gateway field is match for vpn.domain.at adddress and the Save button is disabled - I can't save this type of connection.
Also I want to point that I haven't certificate and do not used any certificates on the windows.

2. Attempt with PPTP:

[image]

In this case I also do not know

- what I need to use in the Gateway field, NT Domain field.
- where I need use the KEY
- the password field isn't available!!!

So I can't complete connection with both option. Please help me with this isssue.

Answer (score 1):

Going back to your first screenshot, click on the **Type** dropdown (under Authentication) and select **Password with Certificates (TLS)**. This should give you all the fields you need.

Comment: Thanks, I found the field with KEY, but Save button steel disabled

Comment: Did you fill in all the fields?

Comment: I updated question

Comment: What about the **Private Key** field?

Comment: This field means I need have key like a file. But I have only key-password

Comment: When you created your VPN account, it should have asked to create connection files (including the keys) so that you could just import that instead of manually setting up the VPN connection. If that doesn't work, then I'm not sure I can help you. This is what I did with **Private Tunnel**; works the same on Windows and Linux.